# Adding data to the rows in Table layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Am trying to create an EPG kind of layout and i referred this
([Print out ArrayList content in Android TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695380/print-out-arraylist-content-in-android-tablelayout))
And my problem is when am trying to add rows, they are getting added as a new rows but i need those values to be added in existing rows. 
Here is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="354dp"
        android:background="#6495ED"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >


     <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:text="Some Text " 
                />

             <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:text="Some Text"
              />

             <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:text="Some Text" />



        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and my java file is

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
            for(int i=0;i<channel_arraylist.size();i++)
            {

                TableRow tableRow2=new TableRow(VideoDatabase1.this);
                localchannel1= channel_arraylist.get(i);

                  TextView tvid=new TextView(VideoDatabase1.this);
                  tvid.setText(""+Integer.toString(localchannel1.getID()));
             tableRow2.addView(tvid);

            table.addView(tableRow2);
```

Comment: so data is not added properly in table layout??

Comment: yes data is not added in table rows.. instead its getting added below the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

#### TableRow tableRow2=new TableRow(VideoDatabase1.this);

to

#### TableRow tableRow2=((TableRow)table.getChildAt(0));

Also, set a breakpoint in line:

```
for(int i=0;i<channel_arraylist.size();i++)
```

And watch your "table" variable in *debug mode*. It must contain at least 1 child. It must help.

Regarding your question: TableRow must be added below because you add a new row to tableLayout. And it's normally.

Comment: Hi @Panda first thanks for your answer. I tried your code. but its showing class cast exception.Am a newbie. so can you explain me in detail about this

Comment: Sorry 4 this. Yes you can cast right side to (TableRow). I've update my answer.

Comment: The values are getting inserted in right side of table layout but not on table layout..

Answer (score 4):

My answer for your question.

```
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private TableLayout table;    

    data.add("Samsung");
    data.add("Apple");
    data.add("Pixle");
    data.add("Vivo");
    data1.add(" $109");
    data1.add(" $200");
    data1.add(" $399");
    data1.add(" $290");        


    table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mytable);

    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
    {
        TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
        String phone = data.get(i);
        String amount = data1.get(i);
        TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(phone);
        TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(amount);
        row.addView(tv1);
        row.addView(tv2);
        table.addView(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the solution. To add the views to the particular table just do

```
TextView tvid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
          tvid.setText(localchannel1.getName());
```

Here `id` refers to the `id` you declared in your layout file. Simply this will insert the value in the corresponding column. Thanks for everything.

Comment: for what ?? for help or remember to send request??

Answer (score -1):

/*THIS IS A FULL EXAMPLE ON HOW TO FILL A TABLE LAYOUT FROM A DATABASE USING A FRAMGENT AND RECEIVING PARAMETERS USING A BUNDLE.
I HOPE THIS CODE COULD HELP YOU
*/

```
package co.m3medios.nagaapp.Fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import co.m3medios.nagaapp.R;
import co.m3medios.nagaapp.SQLite.ConexionSQLiteHelper;
import co.m3medios.nagaapp.Utils.Utilidades;

public class ListasPreciosFragment extends Fragment {

    public TableLayout listaPreciosGeneral;
    public String[] titulo= {"Referencia", "Colección","Silueta", "Clas Producto", "Composición", "M", "Vende", "Color", "Tallas", "Agotados", "Observaciones", "Entrega", "Tiquete"};
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ListasPreciosFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ListasPreciosFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ListasPreciosFragment fragment = new ListasPreciosFragment();


        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listas_precios, container, false);
        listaPreciosGeneral = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabla_listaPreciosGral);

        llenarTablaGeneral();
```

return view;
        }

```
    private void llenarTablaGeneral() {
        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(getContext());
        tbrow0.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2d2d5a"));
        tbrow0.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //LLENAR EL HEADER DE LA TABLA

        for(String c:titulo){
            TextView tv0 = new TextView(getContext());
            tv0.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv0.setTextSize(18);
            tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tv0.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tv0.setText(c);
            tbrow0.addView(tv0);
        }
        //INSERTAR TITULOS
        listaPreciosGeneral.addView(tbrow0);


        //ABRIR LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS PARA ESCRITURA
        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getContext(), "nagamobile", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();//abro la BD para escritura

        db.beginTransaction();

        int color = 0;
        try
        {
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ Utilidades.TABLA_LISTAPRECIOS;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
            if(cursor.getCount() >0)
            {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    // LEER LOS DATOS DE LAS COLUMNAS POR FILA

                    int id_lista_p = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    String referencia = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("referencia"));
                    String coleccion = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("coleccion"));
                    String silueta = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("silueta"));
                    String clasProducto = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("clasProducto"));
                    String composicion = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("composicion"));
                    String m = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("m"));
                    String vende = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("vende"));
                    String colorListaP = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("colorListaP"));
                    String tallas = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tallas"));
                    String agotada = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("agotada"));
                    String observaciones = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("observaciones"));
                    String entrega = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("entrega"));
                    String tiquete = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tiquete"));
                    tiquete = "$ "+tiquete;

                    // CREAR LAS FILAS DE DATOS POR CADA ITERACION
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
                    row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    //CAMBIAR EL COLOR DE LAS FILAS
                        if ( color % 2 == 0) {
                            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));//LINEA BLANCA
                        }
                        else {
                            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#abb1b3"));//LINEA GRIS
                        }

                   //RENDERIZAR LINEA A LINEA
                    String[] lpRender={referencia,coleccion,silueta,clasProducto,composicion,m,vende,colorListaP,
                                     tallas,agotada,observaciones,entrega,tiquete};

                    for(String text:lpRender) {
                        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());//CADA BUCLE INSTANCIA UN NUEVO OBJETO PARA CREAR LA FILA
                        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2d2d5a"));
                        tv.setTextSize(14);
                        tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        tv.setText(text);
                        row.addView(tv);
                    }
                    listaPreciosGeneral.addView(row);
                    color ++;//AUMENTA POR CADA ITERACION PARA CAMBIAR EL COLOR DE LA LINEA
                }
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
           void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe DON'T YELL and fixup the formatting. Also, some words describing how this addresses the question at hand instead of just a wall of code would make this answer more useful.