# android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, exception

I wrote my first android application, simple CRUD. But after I changed GridView to TableLayout I get following error:

```
android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.TableLayout
```

Here is my activity:

```
public class AllActivity extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase sampleDB;
    private TableLayout tableList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all);





        sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("my_app",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);


        String query = "SELECT * FROM BOOKS;";
        Cursor cursor = sampleDB.rawQuery(query, null);


        tableList = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableList);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

                TextView id = new TextView(this);
                id.setText(""+cursor.getLong(0));

                TextView title = new TextView(this);
                title.setText(cursor.getString(1));

                TextView author = new TextView(this);
                author.setText(cursor.getString(2));


                row.addView(id);
                row.addView(title);
                row.addView(author);

                tableList.addView(row);



            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }


}
```

My view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any tips what am I doing wrong?
I did everything like in [Print out ArrayList content in Android TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695380/print-out-arraylist-content-in-android-tablelayout) but can't get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.TableLayout
```

You have

```
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableList" // table row
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableRow>
```

But while initializing you have

```
 tableList = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableList);
 // casting tablerow to tablelayout
```

You may want to check

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

You can also find examples of table layout in the sdk samples @

android-sdk/samples/android-17/ApiDemos/res/layout/table_layout_1.xml

Comment: Of course! Damn... stupid error. I was sure I dragged TableLayout from visual editor. Thanks for help. I'll accept answer in 8min